# UWP Community Toolkit DataGrid: cannot declare columns

Tags: xaml, uwp, datagrid, windows-community-toolkit

I recently moved Community Toolkit to v7.0.2. Since then, the DataGrid cannot declare Columns.
I am getting "Failed to add DataGridTextColumn to ObservableCollection. Element not found."

I applied the requested changes to the app.xaml resource declaration. I also removed the DataGrid reference from source & re-build, to no avail... This one seems to be stuck.

Here are the relevant XAML declarations:

```
<Page
    ...
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
/>
<controls:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ...}" >
   <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
      <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
   </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
</controls:DataGrid>
```

This seems to be a breaking change inside the Toolkit, as my code has not been changed before this error occurred.

Any idea? Artefacts somewhere in the build cache? Running VS2017-15.9.33

Comment: I have created a DataGrid with **Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls 7.0.2** on VS2019, DataGridTextColumn works well on my side. My suggestion is that you could create a new blank app and re-install the package, then reference it. If the new app still has error, you could provide us a sample for testing through OneDrive or GitHub. Besides, the Package reference doesn’t need to be declared in app.xaml resource, you only need to add its reference at the top of your page.

Comment: Thank you. I might just uninstall VS2017 and reinstall the whole lot to see if there is a corrupt cache somewhere... Will keep you posted.   BTW, please remove the reference to the app.xaml changes from the ReadMe, that just caused unnecessary work and is a red herring. Thanks.

Comment: No go. Here is the skeleton UWP solution: https://github.com/jhwheuer/TestDataGrid. Does not work with the error code I mentioned in the initial upload.

Comment: I have tested your sample, this reports "Microsoft.UI.Xaml nuget package requires TargetPlatformVersion >= 10.0.18362.0 (current project is 17763)". So I changed the target version of project to the latest version(19041), and the code work well.

Comment: Oh that is funny because I do not see 18362 in the available SDKs for CS2017. Where can I get my hands on that release?

Comment: Maybe you don't have 18362 or higher version sdk, you could download it through Visual Studio Installer.(Open Installer ->Modify->Individul components-> windows10 SDK(10.0.18362.0)->modify).

Comment: That's what I am telling you. The "windows10 SDK(10.0.18362.0)" component does not appear. 17763 is the highest version I am seeing. I'll add my screenshot into the GitHub project for you to take a look at...

Comment: https://github.com/jhwheuer/TestDataGrid/blob/master/2021-06-10%20Screenshot%20available%20SDK%20components.png

Answer (score 0):

VS2017 has the highest SDK version is 17763, so I suggest you could install VS2019 to own the higher version sdk. Or you could lower the Community Toolkit version so that it support more windows SDK version.

If you don’t want do these as above, the team is actively answering the question about WindowsCommunityToolkit [here](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues), you could report your issue here, which will help you get more help quickly.